# Model DisplayFormat's DataFormat Error in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Here is my  model to format the date based on the current culture.

I tried to avoid hard coding like **DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"**
The reason for doing below is to get the current culture pattern

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Date is required")]
 [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true,
               DataFormatString = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.ToString())]
[Display(Name = "Date", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Global))]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

and in .cshtml

```
@Html.TextBox("Date", 
    Model.Date.ToString("d", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat), new { @class = "datePicker" })
```

**Issue**: I am getting an error

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression,  typeof
>   expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Is there way to show a current culture based short date in MVC TextBox Helper?

Answer (score -1):

`{0:d}` is the current culture `ShortDatePattern`,

instead of

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.ToString())]
```

You should use

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = {0:d})]
```

Having set that, DataFormatString is only used in EditorFor and DisplayFor. So you should change your view to

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { @class = "datepicker" })
```

Remember to add `@model YourModel` at the top of the view

Comment: `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { @class = "datepicker" })` won't work - the second parameter is additional view data, not html attributes! Check [EditorFor documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406462(v=vs.108).aspx)